# extract function not working in drupal

Tags: php, jquery, drupal

I want to change the  home page in drupal site then I have replace the code of **page--front.tpl.php** with our code which is calling from
**html.tpl.php** and then I want to show a popup after clicking on button which is showing in our home page the name of page which will be 
open after clicking this button is **country.php** but it is not showing and showing some error

```
Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, 
null given in /home/letseat/public_html/m2/sites/all/themes/leo/change-country.php on line  234
```

Earlier in drupal site this popup is showing on mouseover on search button (in every page of site) plz help me how can I fix it.

**note:**
country.php is my page in which i have my own data which i want to show on pop up

please help by suggesting me what to do.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I don't see your code, the only thing we can do is suggesting you to check parameters that you send to extract() function.

e.g:

```
$result = is_array($my_array) ? extract($my_array) : 0;
```